# Renaming multiple files with date pattern using rename

Tags: linux, shell, rename

I've read through multiple posts regarding this issue, but none of the proposed solutions seem to work for me. This may be just related to a typo or something similarly stupid, but I just haven't found my error for a few hours now.

I have quite a lot of files I'd like to rename. There are two very similar patterns to them. The files are named either like this:

```
xx-xx-xxxx-Protocoll_xx.xx.xxxx.md
```

or like this:

```
xx-xx-xxxx-Protocoll xx.xx.xxxx.md
```

I would like them to be named like this:

```
Protocoll xx.xx.xxxx.md
```

I've tried the following configurations:

```
rename -v -n 's/....-..-..-Protocoll_(..\...\.....)\.md/Protocoll $1\.md/' *.md
rename -v -n 's/....-..-..-//' *.md
rename -v -n 's/....-..-..-/' '' *.md
rename -v -n 's/....-..-..-Protocoll_(..\...\.....)\.md' 's/Protocoll $1\.md/' *.md
rename -v -n '....-..-..-Protocoll_(..\...\.....)\.md' 'Protocoll $1\.md' *.md
```

I always get the same error code `4`.
I'm using the following version of `rename`:
`rename from util-linux 2.33.1`

Answer (score 0):

Rename will keep unmatched characters in filename.

So one solution could be:

```
rename -v -n 's/^.*(Proto)/$1/' *.md
```

Or better to transform `" "` and `"_"` to `" "`

```
rename -v -n 's/^.*(Protocoll)./$1 /' *.md
```

Comment: I did a quick test, created a file `test.txt` and ran the command `rename -v -n 's/^.*(st)/21$1/' *.txt`. The result was `rename: not enough arguments`, so I guess I need it in a form of `rename old-name new-name file` instead of `rename regex file`. But how do I accomplish this with what I'm trying to do?